# Как остановить демон?

Tags: c++, linux, c, демон

У меня никак не получается остановить работу демона, что я и пытаюсь сделать с помощью параметра `stop`. Подскажите, как лучше это сделать? И почему `exit(0)` не помогает?

```
  int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

        pid_t pid, sid;

            pid = fork();
            if (pid < 0) {
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            if (pid > 0) {
                    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }

            umask(0);

            sid = setsid();
            if (sid < 0) {
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }


            if ((chdir("/")) < 0) {
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            } 
            //.....................
            //.....................
            //.....................
            //.....................
            if(strcmp(argv[i], "stop") == 0) {

            cout << "Packets are not sniffed.\n" << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: И опять же не удержусь... https://www.facebook.com/progertypical/photos/a.374368692683718.1073741828.374367952683792/1091091214344792/?type=3&theater

Answer (score 4):

Дело даже не в типи сигнала, который Вы посылаете, а в том, что Вы не понимаете, как это всё работает...

Вот что вы пишите:

```
pid = fork();
if (pid < 0) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (pid > 0) {
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Т.е. Ваша программа завершается и когда pid<0 и тогда, когда pid>0.
Остаётся только одно значение - ноль. Но это означает, что мы находимся в ДОЧЕРНЕМ процессе! В результате, команда

```
kill(pid, SIGCONT);
```

посылает сигнал процессу с pid == 0. Это Вы о чём?! Если Ваш дочерний процесс хочет сделать харикири, то это делается с помощью exit(0);

Если же Вы хотите убить дочерний из родителя, то надо сигнал посылать в ветке, где pid > 0. А сигнал может быть, ну хоть, SIGINT... Это то же самое, сто нажать Ctrl/C.

Отвечаю на просьбу в комменте: " ответить на буквальный вопрос в заголовке".

Есть только ОДИН способ убить процесс -  послать ему сигнал, который не может быть обработан. Процесс (любой) не может обработать сигнал, если он не создал обработчик этого сигнала, либо этот сигнал в принйипе не обрабатывается (-9).

Для того, что бы отправить сигнал процессу, необходимо знать его PID. А вот здесь возможно два варианта:
1) Вы знаете его PID потому, что сами его создали с помощью операции fork.
2) Этот процесс - правильно написанный демон и он честно положил в каталог /var/run свой pid-файл, в котором и записан его pid. При этом имя файла должно совпадать с именем запущенного демона и его легко понять.

Таким образом, Ваш дочерний процесс должен записать свой pid в pid-файл в каталоге /ar/run. А ваш процесс, который его убивает - должен прочитать этот файл, взять из него pid и вызвать kill() с этим pid-ом.

Вроде - всё...

Comment: я согласен, что во многом еще не разобрался. но я понимаю, что при каждом новом вызове программы я завершаю родительский процесс и начинаю новый. так вот мне надо что бы он работал до тех пор, пока я не запущу еще раз программу из командой `stop`. тут я ожидаю, что закрою и родительскийif `(pid > 0) {
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}` и дочерний (через kill) процессы. но вот если заменить `kill` на `exit`, то процесс всеравно будет работать.

Comment: тоесть, тут я делал по такому принцыпу, что каждый дочерний процес должен вызываться с какойто командой.

Comment: Не могли бы вы для людей, которые из поисковика, благодаря заголовку, этот вопрос найдут (основная аудитория Stack Overflow), ответить на буквальный вопрос в заголовке или подправить заголовок вопроса так, чтобы он соответствовал проблеме в теле вопроса (стараясь не изменять сути вопроса, чтобы люди с похожими заблуждениями как у автора могли бы по прежнему найти этот вопрос). Я бы сам сделал, но не могу краткую формулировку для заголовка придумать.

Answer (score 1):

Начнём с того, что вы вообще не разобрались в сути процессов. Если вы запускаете программу ещё раз, то порождается совершенно новый процесс, и разумеется, exit вызовет завершение именно этого нового процесса, а не того, который у вас запущен как демон.
Как правило в программах, поддерживающих режим демона это делается следующим образом: PID процесса-демона сохраняется где-нибудь в общедоступном месте (/var/run, /tmp), а процесс запущенный с параметром --stop вычитывает PID процесса-демона, и делает ему kill с этим значением PID.

Comment: согласен. Я не разобрался. Времени не было. Поэтому обратился за помощью.

Answer (score 0):

SIGCONT не может помочь в данном случае, потому что этот сигнал продолжает выполнение остановленного процесса, а если процесс уже выполняется, этот сигнал игнорируется.